# WPF two way data bind to custom data type in observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm trying to data bind to a custom data type property `FormulaField` in WPF. I don't understand if there's something I've missed or if what I'm trying to do can't be done?

I've followed the convention of how I've bound to a primitive and found that hasn't worked, there's not update on the `FormulaField` property. I've also noticed that the custom data type set method is never hit. I'm using MVVM.

A model:

```
 public class OBQModel : NotificationObject
    {    
        private FormulaField _tovLitres;
        public FormulaField TOVLitres
        {
            get
            {
                if (_tovLitres.UsesFormula)
                {
                    _tovLitres.Value = ConversionHelper.USBarrelsToLitres(_tovBarrels);
                }
                return _tovLitres;
            }
            set
            {
                _tovLitres = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TOVLitres");
            }
        }
}
```

The `NotificationObject` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public abstract class NotificationObject : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
        {
            var propertyName = GetPropertyName(action);
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
        {
            var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
            var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
            return propertyName;
        }

        protected internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

FormulaField looks like this:

```
public class FormulaField
{
    public bool UsesFormula { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT
Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `FormulaField` goes stack overflow...

```
public class FormulaField : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool UsesFormula { get; set; }
        public double Value
        {
            get
            {
                return Value;
            }
            set
            {
                Value = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

The Models sit inside an `ObservableCollection` in a ViewModel.

An illustration of the View:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OBQModelCollection}">    
     <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="new TOV (L)" Width="100">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox BorderThickness="0" 
                  Text="{Binding TOVLitres.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the problem would be that you are binding the text to a attribute of the FormulaField class, and this attribute doesn´t send the RaisePropertyChanged event. Try adding it to the "Value" attribute setter.

Comment: @superarce try adding what to the "Value" attribute setter?

Comment: Yes, you have an attribute in the "FormulaField" class called "Value", and the textbox Text is binded to it. I think that you have to edit his setter to apply the new value and add the RaisePropertyChanged event. Like you have done with the TOVLitres object.

Comment: when I do that I get a stack overflow exception...

Comment: Smells like circular dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon what you wrote, you are raising INPC on "LiquidGOVLitres", which doesn't seem to appear in your code listing, but you are binding to "TOVLitres".

Fixing this inconsistency will help, but you will also need to implement INPC on the FormulaField if you want changes to its members to be part of your UI.

ETA:  After the clarifying edit to your code listing, the remaining task is to implement INPC on your FormulaField class and raise the event accordingly.

Also, if you are using 4.5 you can investigate the new Member Info class which helps avoid the use of magic strings in INPC.

Finally, for semantic clarity, it wouldn't hurt to rename "Value" to "FormulaValue"...

To avoid recursion, try this model...

```
    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _value; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (Math.Abs(value - _value) > Double.Epsilon)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, that property is irrelevant for this. I will edit my question.

Comment: So I do this and get stack overflow

Comment: Yes, because the setter of "Value" (statement "Value = value") invokes the setter of "Value" and this is a recursive call.  Consider using a backing field, preferably private.

Comment: ah so that's what the private is for, thanks very much! this worked and you helped me understand what was going on